# How to get locale for localeCompare from i18next?

Tags: javascript, i18next

Our project is using [i18next](https://www.i18next.com/overview/api) for translations, and I'm currently needing to sort strings using [String.prototype.localeCompare](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare)

How would I go about getting a code like `'en'`, `'fr'`, `'en-US'`, etc from i18next? Does i18next default to a specific code? Would I need to use an i18next instance or the default export?

I believe these might be called "BCP 47 language tags"

Thanks

Comment: Are you looking for [i18next.language](https://www.i18next.com/overview/api#language)?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so the brief answer is that you just use `i18next.language`

In our case, it did matter that we used the correct instance, not just the default import. We also used an additional layer called `react-i18next` as shown below.

```
import { I18nContext } from "react-i18next";

...

const { i18n } = useContext(I18nContext);

...

return isLocaleCompareSupported()
    ? aText.localeCompare(bText, i18n.language)
    : aText.localeCompare(bText);
```